# How does this Swift Code WORK ??!!

Tags: ios, swift

I wonder why the following piece of code does not crash even though I try to force type cast to the wrong type and call a method on it !!!

```
struct Apple{

}

struct Mango{

}

struct Orange{

}

func getValue(dict:[String:Any?]){

for value in dict.values{

    if ( (value is [Apple]) && ((value as! [Apple]).isEmpty == false) ) {
        print("Apple")
    }
    if value is [Mango]{
        print("Mango")
    }
    if value is [Orange]{
        print("Orange")
    }

}

}

getValue(dict: ["name":[Mango()]])
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: The "check and then conditionally do" pattern should be avoided, particularly when Swift gives you an option to do both in one shot: `if let apples = value as? [Apple], !apples.isEmpty { ... `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really poor quality code. But it doesn't crash because the second operand of an AND operation is lazily evaluated. That is, when the first operand if `false`, the result of the AND operation will be `false`, regardless of the second operand, so the value of the second operand is not even evaluated. It is said to be "short circuited".

```
func f1() -> Bool {
    print("Left side evaluated to `false`")
    return false
}

func f2() -> Bool {
    print("Right side evaluated")
    return true
}

print(f1() && f2())

// Outputs:
// Left side evaluated to `false`
// false
```

Comment: Thanks ! That clears it . Sorry about the quality of the code , I just cooked it up in 5 minutes to simulate a code that I had seen in a project